# Returning pointer to pointer of structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am working on a database which has multiple structs. I have defined a function which loads data from a csv file and stores each line as a struct. I store them using a double pointer, so one pointer points to multiple pointers for each struct variable. The function does return the double pointer correctly, however I get a warning: return from incompatible pointer type.

My code is as follows:

```
struct part** loadParts(char* fileName, int m)
{
    typedef struct part
    {
        int id;
        int cost;
    } Part;
    FILE* fptr = fopen(fileName, "r");
    //creat pointer to array of pointers to part structs
    Part** parts;
    parts = malloc((nParts) * sizeof(Part *));
    //length of one line
    char line[1000];

    //while new items can be added
    int i;
    i=0;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fptr)!= NULL)
    {
            parts[i] = malloc(sizeof(Part));
            //get id
            int id = atoi(strtok(line, ";"));
            parts[i]->id = id;
            // get cost
            int id = atoi(strtok(line, ";"));
            parts[i]->cost = cost;
    i++;
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    return parts;
}
```

Does anybody know why this warning occurs? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: can you tell on which statement in your code you get the warning?

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake while copying the code! :)

Comment: Are you sure the `struct part` is the same as `Part` in your function? If I were you, I'd have one global definition of this type and got rid of this second definition inside the function.

Comment: @SMFSW Thanks, on the line of return parts;

Comment: @ForceBru Thanks! Yes it is the same. So you would get rid of the 'Part' at the end of the struct definition?

Comment: @Drent, I'd remove this definition altogether as there's already one in the global namespace.

Comment: @ForceBru Thanks, I changed this.

Comment: @Drent, is it working now?

Comment: @SMFSW Thank you, I made the cast but still I got the same warning: return from incompatible pointer. My code is working in the end though, but as I am new to C, I tried to avoid any warnings..

Comment: @ForceBru No, still the same warning..

Comment: @SMFSW the warning is there to highlight a problem with the code that needs fixing, not something to work around with an ill thought out kludge!

Comment: @SMFSW Do not suggest ways to work around warnings unless you know what the warnings are about and that they can be ignored. All you're doing is hiding the problem.

Comment: @SMFSW the function return type differs from the type of the variable being returned - changing them to be identical should remove the warning.

Comment: @SMFSW and yes I often write code that has no warnings - I even compile with -Werror just to make sure I don't get lazy and leave warnings in my code :)

Comment: @ForceBru, it worked! It was indeed the problem with the definition. Many thanks! I have been working the whole day on this..

Comment: @SMFSW Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: @Drent, awesome! You're welcome!

Comment: @ChrisTurner Yeah, I also try to look into every warning but sometimes it takes me quite a long time haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have in outline:

```
struct part** loadParts(char* fileName, int m)
{
    typedef struct part
    {
        int id;
        int cost;
    } Part;
    …
    Part** parts;
    …
    parts = …
    …
    return parts;
}
```

There is no way that this will compile without warnings.  The `struct part` used in the function signature is, by definition, wholly unrelated to the `struct part` defined inside the function.  You are, therefore, returning a pointer to one type in a function that is expecting to return a pointer to a different type, even though those types may both be spelled `struct part`.  There isn't even a way to cast your code out of trouble.

As indicated in the comments, the structure definition must come outside the function, before the function definition (and probably before any declaration — and typically in a header file that's used wherever the structure is used).

One way to fix the code, therefore, is:

```
typedef struct part
{
    int id;
    int cost;
} Part;

struct part **loadParts(char *fileName, int m)
{
    …
    Part **parts;
    …
    parts = …
    …
    return parts;
}
```

You could have the function return a `Part **` in this scenario.

However, the function should now be defined as `static` unless you have a header to contain the structure definition.  If you don't have a header, you can't (reliably) access the structure type in other source files.  (It can be done by writing the code out twice, but writing code twice should be anathema — it becomes a maintenance liability before you've finished typing, or copy'n'pasting, the second copy.)

It is possible that you are dealing with an opaque type; the code outside this file doesn't need to know about the structure details.  That's legitimate; it can even be (very) beneficial.  You just need a different way of writing things, though:

Header:

```
typedef struct part Part;
extern struct part **loadParts(char *fileName, int m);
```

If you decide not to expose the name `Part`, you could use this header instead:

```
struct part;
extern struct part **loadParts(char *fileName, int m);
```

The first line says "there is a type `struct part` but the details will be supplied later, if you need them".  The second declares the function returning a pointer to pointer to `struct part` value. The `extern` is optional; I use it — many people don't.  In this code, the first line is optional.  However, if you had `extern int num_parts(struct part **list);` as a function, you would need that to appear after the `loadParts()` declaration, or you would need the `struct part;` line to ensure that the type in the prototype is not new.

Source:

```
struct part 
{
    int id;
    int cost;
};

struct part **loadParts(char *fileName, int m)
{
    …
    Part **parts;
    …
    parts = …
    …
    return parts;
}
```

You need to worry about header guards in the header to ensure idempotency. (In this example, there's no problem of self-containedness, but you should also ensure that your headers are self-contained — there are multiple questions on SO which will explain those terms if you search).

Comment: Thank you very much for this extensive explanation! I already implemented your suggested way to fix my code and it worked indeed. I indeed have a header so I dont need to make the function static. I will look into the idempotency part of your answer as I am not familiar with this (yet). Have a nice weekend!